# Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string in laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.4

In my laravel model i am using

> getTimeagoAttribute()

in this function i am try to get that timeago value for example when i post one review at 11.30 and now the time is 12:30 means i want to display 1 hour ago near the review and code inside my function is

```
public function getTimeagoAttribute()
    {
        $mytime = \Carbon\Carbon::now();
        $date = $mytime->toDateTimeString()->diffForHumans();
        return $date;
    }
```

When i try to run the code its show me an error  `Call to a member function diffForHumans() on string` is this correct way to achieve what i want or is there any other method to acheive this..

This is how i achieve in my blade view

```
<span class="pull-right">{{$review->timeago}}</span>
```

please help me out to achieve this ..

Answer (score 2):

You should make it like this :

```
return \Carbon\Carbon::now()->diffForHumans();
```

this `$mytime->toDateTimeString()` will return a string not a `Carbon` object

Comment: Yeah thank you bara it works fine but it the time didnot changed whenever i am view that post it shows 1 second ago

Comment: its because you are taking time from `now`.. so it will always be 1 second ago. try to do this `return Carbon::createFromDate($date)->diffForHumans();`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use the default timestamps, you can use the `created_at` field.

```
public function getTimeAgoAttribute()
{
    return $this->created_at->diffForHumans();
}
```

Use it like

```
<span class="pull-right">{{ $review->timeAgo }}</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you do is to call the time it was updated/created from the model, then call the diffForHumans() function, just like the code below:

```
MyPostModel::all()->first()->updated_at->diffForHumans();
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the below code,

> return
>   Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC(strtotime($date))->diffForHumans();
>
> ```
>    function timeAgo($date)
>    {
>         return Carbon::createFromTimestampUTC(strtotime($date))->diffForHumans();
>    }
> ```

it compares with current date time and gives you the result